# nHibernate - Do I have to use transaction for single but referenced update?

Tags: nhibernate

Here is my basic nHibernate entity:

```
public class Patients
{
    public virtual int Id { get; protected set; }
    public virtual string First_Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string Last_Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string Pesel { get; set; }
    public virtual string Gender { get; set; }
    public virtual string Height { get; set; }   
    public virtual string Comments { get; set; }   

    public virtual Adresses Address { get; set; }
    public virtual Adresses CorrespondencyAddress { get; set; }

    public virtual StudyPayer DefaultPayer { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime? BirthDate { get; set; }
    public virtual string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime RegistrationDate { get; set; }  

    public virtual string Citizenship { get; set; }
    public virtual string Country_Region { get; set; }
    public virtual string EMail { get; set; }     
    public virtual string Doc_Id_Number { get; set; } 

}
```

And here is Addresses entity that is referenced in Patients:

```
public class Adresses
{
    public virtual int Id { get; protected set; }
    public virtual string Street { get; set; }
    public virtual string HomeNumber { get; set; }
    public virtual string PostalCode { get; set; }
    public virtual string City { get; set; }
    public virtual string Country { get; set; }
}
```

In my code I add an address for patient and then I want to insert both:

```
    Patients pacjent = new Patients();
    pacjent.First_Name = model.First_Name;
    pacjent.Last_Name = model.Last_Name;

    Adresses corAddress = new Adresses();
    corAddress.City = model.CityCorrespondency;
    corAddress.HomeNumber = model.HouseNumberCorrespondency;
    corAddress.PostalCode = model.PostCodeCorrespondency;
    corAddress.Street = model.StreetCorrespondency;

    pacjent.CorrespondencyAddress = corAddress;
```

In database layer it will take at least 2 inserts or updates.

The question is if I need to save it within the transaction:

```
using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
{
    transaction.Begin();
    session.SaveOrUpdate(pacjent);
    transaction.Commit();
}
```

or simply nHibernate take care of transactioning:

```
session.SaveOrUpdate(pacjent);
```

Comment: If you want to have reliable software, there is no other option than using [ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) transaction. Anything else will always be hazardous. You can, but you should not call WRITE without transaction...

Comment: I know ACID but my question is if nHibernate take care of transactioning in this specific situations: one call of SaveOrUpdate() but 2 inserts to DB.

Comment: The answer is NO. NHibernate will use implicit transactin, i.e. each statement will have its own ACID solution. That said, if you do not wrap that in EXPLICIT transaction it can happen that one INSERT or UPDATE will succeed the other won't. So, DO NOT EVER use the implicit one. Always wrap it in Transaction. And what's more, the real INSERT UPDATE is not related to Save() but to session.Flush()...

Comment: Thanks. I have just check it in practical situation :)

Comment: Great to see that. I believe that you will properly start transaction and commit it at the end of the COMPLETE request. ;) That will give you fruit you need ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make it clear, let me provide these facts. NHibernate in fact is build on top of ADO.NET, and as we can read in doc, [1.4. Playing with cats](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#quickstart-playingwithcats):

> ... In an ISession, every database operation occurs inside a transaction that isolates the database operations (even read-only operations). We use NHibernate's ITransaction API to abstract from the underlying transaction strategy (in our case, ADO.NET transactions)...

Another important part of doc is the:

#### [9.6. Flush](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#manipulatingdata-flushing)

> From time to time the ISession will execute the SQL statements needed to synchronize the ADO.NET connection's state with the state of objects held in memory. This process, flush, occurs by default at the following points
>
> - from some invocations of `Find()` or `Enumerable()`
> - from `NHibernate.ITransaction.Commit()`
> - from `ISession.Flush()`

...

> It is possible to change the default behavior so that flush occurs less frequently. The FlushMode class defines three different modes: only flush at commit time *(and **only when the NHibernate ITransaction API** is used)*, flush automatically using the explained routine *(will only work inside an explicit NHibernate ITransaction)*, or never flush unless `Flush()` is called explicitly...

That is important to know, that NHibernate creates abstraction called `ISession`, which takes all the command like `Save()` or `SaveOrUpdate()` ... but the extraction of these into INSERT and UPDATE is done on **`session.Flush()`**.

Above we've seen, that we can use transactions. But in fact we do not have to *(very **bad** approach)*. We can use the explicit transaction, which is created arround each and every INSERT, UPDATE... commands - but separately. Let's have a closer look at this:

#### [Difference between Implicit and Explicit Transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4986683/1679310)

Let me cite from one of the [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4986716/1679310):

> ... By default the database operates in explicit transaction mode with autocommiting transactions enabled. That actually means **that unless an explicit transaction is started using BEGIN TRANSACTION, every data modification is started in a separate transaction which is committed after the statement.** That allows the database to rollback an entire statement when it fails (for instance a bulk insert, or an insert that modifies other data in a trigger).

And thats's the issue. If we won't use transaction as a wrapper, we can end up with inconsistent state. Some WRITE operations could be commited, some could be rolled back.

> **And that's why we always should use explicit transaction, NHibernate transaction API, to be sure that persisted was ALL or NOTHING**

Answer (score -1):

If you're using SaveOrUpdate outside of a transaction it will commit automatically - if one of the statements crashes all statements before it are commited.

With the explicit transaction it should work correctly and rollback if there are any exceptions. By the way you have to map the address correctly - otherwise it isn't saved.

Another point you don't have to call transaction.Begin() - it is started automatically with session.BeginTransaction()

```
using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
{
    session.SaveOrUpdate(pacjent);
    transaction.Commit();
}
```

Comment: Both codes works correctly now :) But there are at least 2 inserts to DB so what if one of them will fail? If it will clean also second insert from DB automatically without transactioning?

Mappings are OK. Thanks for other suggestions...

Comment: I have check it in practical situation and it has left inserted data in Address table when failed on Patient table.

Comment: But with the transaction it worked correctly ? I am going to correct my answer - sorry for beein wrong

Comment: Write an answear similar to Radim Köhler comment that is below question. It is the correct answear :)