# what is the meaning of explicit transaction and implicit transaction and give some explanation with examples

Tags: mysql, database, transactions, implicit, explicit

what is the "meaning" of **explicit** transaction and **implicit** transaction and give some *explanation* with examples?
I am not clear with the words explicit and implicit transactions.and their differences.

Comment: Maybe offer up some context. Or watch the impeachment hearing, as this is essentially what's being discussed.

Comment: did you mean this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4986683/difference-between-implicit-and-explicit-transaction ?